# R8 and ProGuard: Missing class error in data class that is using @Keep annotation

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-r8

For some reason, one of our data class model is being obfuscated or removed during build and we had to add `@Keep` annotation to it to work.

```
@Keep
data class CommonNotification(
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val channel: String,
    val action: String = DEFAULT_VALUE_STRING,
    val actionData: String? = DEFAULT_VALUE_STRING,
    val bigImage: String? = DEFAULT_VALUE_STRING,
    val environment: String = BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE
)
```

But running `./gradlew lint` is failing with this error

Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in

```
/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/Mobile/Android/App/app/libs/AndroidCommon/build/outputs/mapping/debug/missing_rules.txt.

ERROR: R8: Missing class java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory (referenced from: java.lang.String com.project.android.common.data.remote.responses.notifications.CommonNotification.toString())
```

Any idea what is the problem and solution?

I tried a solution from this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/250197571) tracker

Adding `-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory` but the getting `Unresolved class name` warning/error in the rules file. I am using `JAVA VERSION_17` and AGP `8.1.1`

Comment: Seems related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/250197571

Comment: @Michael yeah  I added `-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory` rule but I am getting `Unresolved class name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was fixed after adding this rule:

`-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory`

You may get a red error/warning as `Unresolved class name` as it cannot locate the package but that is what `dontwarn` actually do, to exclude a class that is not existing in a project build from lint checking.

References:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/250197571

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/301246673